# Why my React is not able to read internal api (flask) data?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

So, i am a newbie, started to learn `Flask` and `React`. Currently, building a project using `Twitter API` and `Tweepy`.

In React.js, i have a few components; 1 is for navbar which has three nav-items (Home, Search, Random) and a Main component which is the main component rather than having `App.js` do all the 'heavy lifting'. My react (RandomTweets.js) file is not able to display the data from internal api Flask if navigating from `RandomTweets.js` to other nav-item then back to `RandomTweets.js`.

For instance, i could be working on `RandomTweets.js` on vscode, if i saved the current code then data is shown until i switch or click on any nav-item then switch back to `RandomTweets.js`.

**NOTE:** I am using BrowserRouter in App.js, Switch and Route (Main.js).. Don't mind the comments i have on app.py, its for me to see how data is coming back etc...

package.json

```
{
  "name": "front-end",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "start-flask": "cd ../back-end/env && flask run",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"
}
```

RandomTweets.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Toast, Button, Image } from 'react-bootstrap'

const RandomTweetsComponent = () => {
    const [user, setUserData] = useState([])
    const [showA, setShowA] = useState(false);
    const [showB, setShowB] = useState(false);
    const [showC, setShowC] = useState(false);

    const toggleShowA = () => setShowA(!showA);
    const toggleShowB = () => setShowB(!showB);
    const toggleShowC = () => setShowC(!showC);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/randomtweets')
            .then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
                setUserData(data)
            })
    }, [])
    console.log(user)

    return (
        <div
            className="bg-secondary d-flex justify-content-between"
            style={divHeight}>
            <div className="w-25">
                <Toast>
                    <Toast.Header closeButton={false}>
                        <Image
                            className="stick mr-2"
                            // src={user.profile_image.elons}
                            alt="twiiter alike logo"
                            roundedCircle />
                        {/* <strong className="mr-auto">{user.name.elon}</strong> */}
                        {/* <small style={userNameStyle}>@{user.username.elon}</small> */}
                        <Button onClick={toggleShowA}>click me</Button>
                    </Toast.Header>
                    <Toast className="w-100" onClose={toggleShowA} show={showA}>
                        <Toast.Body>Hello, world! This is a toast message.</Toast.Body>
                        <Toast.Body>Hello, world! This is a toast message.</Toast.Body>
                        <Toast.Body>Hello, world! This is a toast message.</Toast.Body>
                        <Toast.Body>Hello, world! This is a toast message.</Toast.Body>
                        <Toast.Body>Hello, world! This is a toast message.</Toast.Body>
                        <Toast.Body>Hello, world! This is a toast message.</Toast.Body>
                        <Toast.Body>Hello, world! This is a toast message.</Toast.Body>
                    </Toast>
                </Toast>
            </div>
            <div className="w-25">
                <Toast>
                    <Toast.Header closeButton={false}>
                        <Image
                            className="stick mr-2"
                            // src={user.profile_image}
                            alt="twiiter alike logo"
                            roundedCircle />
                        {/* <strong className="mr-auto">{user.name}</strong> */}
                        {/* <small style={userNameStyle}>@{user.username}</small> */}
                        <Button onClick={toggleShowB}>click me</Button>
                    </Toast.Header>
                    <Toast className="w-100" onClose={toggleShowB} show={showB}>
                        <Toast.Body>Hello, world! This is a toast message.</Toast.Body>
                        <Toast.Body>Hello, world! This is a toast message.</Toast.Body>
                        <Toast.Body>Hello, world! This is a toast message.</Toast.Body>
                        <Toast.Body>Hello, world! This is a toast message.</Toast.Body>
                        <Toast.Body>Hello, world! This is a toast message.</Toast.Body>
                        <Toast.Body>Hello, world! This is a toast message.</Toast.Body>
                        <Toast.Body>Hello, world! This is a toast message.</Toast.Body>
                    </Toast>
                </Toast>
            </div>
            <div className="w-25">
                <Toast>
                    <Toast.Header closeButton={false}>
                        <Image
                            className="stick mr-2"
                            // src={user.profile_image.bmws}
                            alt="twiiter alike logo"
                            roundedCircle />
                        {/* <strong className="mr-auto">{user.name.bmw}</strong> */}
                        {/* <small style={userNameStyle}>@{user.username.bmw}</small> */}
                        <Button onClick={toggleShowC}>click me</Button>
                    </Toast.Header>
                    <Toast className="w-100" onClose={toggleShowC} show={showC}>
                        <Toast.Body>Hello, world! This is a toast message.</Toast.Body>
                        <Toast.Body>Hello, world! This is a toast message.</Toast.Body>
                        <Toast.Body>Hello, world! This is a toast message.</Toast.Body>
                        <Toast.Body>Hello, world! This is a toast message.</Toast.Body>
                        <Toast.Body>Hello, world! This is a toast message.</Toast.Body>
                        <Toast.Body>Hello, world! This is a toast message.</Toast.Body>
                        <Toast.Body>Hello, world! This is a toast message.</Toast.Body>
                    </Toast>
                </Toast>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

var divHeight = {
    height: '75.25vh',
    minHeight: '75.25vh'
}

var userNameStyle = {
    position: "relative",
    top: "15px",
    right: "15rem",
}

export default RandomTweetsComponent
```

Flask app.py

```
import os
import tweepy
import json
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

consumer_key = os.environ.get('CONSUMER_KEY')
consumer_token = os.environ.get('CONSUMER_SECRET')
access_token_key = os.environ.get('ACCESS_TOKEN')
access_token_key_secret = os.environ.get('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET')

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_token)
auth.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_key_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/randomtweets', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    elons = api.get_user(screen_name='elonmusk')
    gtrs = api.get_user(screen_name='JustGTRs')
    bmws = api.get_user(screen_name='BMW')
    elons_info = api.user_timeline(screen_name='elonmusk', count=5)
    gtrs_info = api.user_timeline(screen_name='JustGTRs', count=5)
    bmws_info = api.user_timeline(screen_name='BMW', count=5)

    andys_tweets_list = []
    gtrs_tweets_list = []
    bmws_tweets_list = []

    for tweets in elons_info:
        andys_tweets_list.append(tweets.text)

    for tweets in gtrs_info:
        gtrs_tweets_list.append(tweets.text)

    for tweets in bmws_info:
        gtrs_tweets_list.append(tweets.text)

    users_info = [{
        "name": {
            "elon": elons.name,
            "gtr": gtrs.name,
            "bmw": bmws.name
        },
        "username": {
            "elons": elons.screen_name,
            "gtrs": gtrs.screen_name,
            "bmws": bmws.screen_name
        },
        "tweets": [
            [elons_tweets_list],
            [gtrs_tweets_list],
            [bmws_tweets_list]
        ],
        "profile_image": {
            "andys": elonss.profile_image_url_https,
            "gtrs": gtrs.profile_image_url_https,
            "bmws": bmws.profile_image_url_https
        }
    }]

    return jsonify(users_info)


# @app.route('/gtr', methods=["GET"])
# def gtr():
#     gtrs = api.get_user(screen_name='JustGTRs')

#     gtrs_info = api.user_timeline(screen_name='JustGTRs', count=5)

#     gtrs_tweets_list = []

#     for tweets in gtrs_info:
#         gtrs_tweets_list.append(tweets.text)

#     user_info = {
#         "name": gtrs.name,
#         "tweets": gtrs_tweets_list,
#         "username": gtrs.screen_name,
#         "profile_image": gtrs.profile_image_url_https
#     }

#     return jsonify(user_info)


# @app.route('/bmw', methods=["GET"])
# def gtr():
#     return


@app.route('/search/:<name>', methods=['GET'])
def maybe(name):
    print(name)

    return '{name}'.format(name)
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Anything in the console? Network tab?

Comment: @JimJ, i'll get this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined..
Console logs the data coming from Flask server
network tab 200.

I was thinking maybe it could be the Promise itself or loading the data from server. Maybe i'm having too much data to fetch all at the same time from server. Not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here might be that `user`, in your JS, *is* undefined at first. Effects run *after* every render. So your first render tries to get the `name` property from `user`, but because of how you called `useState` (`useState([])`), `user` is an empty array at first. You might want to create an empty dummy object (`[{name: ''}]`)

Comment: wow! That fixed my issue! thank you so much, really appreciated!!